# How can I build inner query to find trend top 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, sql-order-by

Question about SQL. The schema is given below:

User(**userID:int**, userName:varchar(30), email:varchar(30), password:varchar(30), status:varchar(15))

Video(**videoID:int**, userID:int, videoTitle:varchar(60), likeCount:int, dislikeCount:int, datePublished:date)

Comment(**commentID:int**, userID:int, videoID:int, commentText:varchar(1000), dateCommented:date)

Watch(**userID:int**, **videoID:int**, dateWatched: date)

Same variables will be using as foreign key. Because of this I do not need to write foreign keys.

A)
List the trending top three videos for a given time interval

(String dateStart, String dateEnd)

A trending video is defined to be the most viewed video in the given interval (i.e., video that is viewed the highest numberof times among all).

You should include dateStart and dateEnd in the result, it is a CLOSED interval.

Output: videoTitle, userName, number of times that the video watched.

I could not figured out how can i find top tree videos. While building inner query what should I do?

Comment: How would you find out how many times a video has been viewed? Start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top 3 videos for a period of time, you can do:

```
select v.videotitle, u.username, count(*) no_watches
from watch w
inner join video v on v.videoid = w.videoid
inner join usr   u on u.userid = v.userid
where w.date_watched between ? and ?
group by v.videoid, u.userid
order by no_watches desc
limit 3
```

The `between` predicate is how I understand the "closed interval". The `?` relate to query parameters that contain the start and end date.

Pre-aggregation might make the query more efficient:

```
select v.videotitle, u.username, w.no_watches
from (
    select videoid, count(*) as no_watches
    from watch
    where date_watched between ? and ?
    group by videoid
    order by no_watches desc limit 3
) w
inner join video v on v.videoid = w.videoid
inner join usr   u on u.userid = v.userid
order by w.no_watches desc
limit 3
```